# Custom error handling for parallel promises

Tags: javascript

I have a set of Promises that I would like to execute in parallel, via `Promise.all`. I would also like to ignore the errors, if any, through:

`Promise.all(promises.map(p => p.catch(() => undefined)));`

I am trying to understand how the returning of `undefined` helps here (can I return the error?). If I wanted some more custom logic, based on a status code, would something like the following work?

```
Promise.all(promises.map(p => p.catch(error => {
    if (error.statusCode === 400) return error;
    throw error;
})));
```

I want to ignore only those errors with a status code of 400, but retain the original behavior for everything else.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach of:

```js
const results = await Promise.all(promises.map(p => p.catch(error => {
  if (error.statusCode === 400) return error;
  throw error;
})));
```

...will work fine, provided that your code that uses `results` knows that it's going to receive a mixture of results and error objects. The version:

```js
const results = await Promise.all(promises.map(p => p.catch(() => undefined)));
```

...causes the `results` array to have the value `undefined` for each case where there was an error. What you do depends on what you want the results to look like.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this should work. The semantics of `catch(fn)` are:

- If `fn` returns a value, the promise is resolved with that value. (Unless the returned value is itself a rejected promise, but that's not the case here.)
- If `fn` throws an exception, the promise is rejected with that exception.

If you return the error from your `catch` handler, `Promise.all` may return an array with a mixture of successful values and errors.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. So in this case, the array will contain all resolved values unless some other error (apart from the `400`) occurred? This is the behavior I want.

Comment: No, it will also contain the errors. E.g. if you send two requests, the first one fails and the second one succeeds, you'll get something like `[errorObject, responseObject]`. If you want to drop the errors entirely, just return `undefined` or `null` from your `catch` handler and filter the array afterwards.